# How do I generate constants to access Ruby array elements?

Tags: ruby, arrays, constants, eval

I use an array to store fieldvalues. To easily add and access elements I use constants as element identifiers.

Until now I did this by hand like this:

```
stages = ["lidnummer","aardf","prest","dt_prest","aantal","bedrag","verstrekker","foutcode"]
values = ["it","can","be","anything",0,5.3,nil,88] 
LIDNUMMER,AARDF,PREST,DT_PREST,AANTAL,BEDRAG,VERSTREKKER,FOUTCODE = 0,1,2,3,1,5,6,7
p values[AARDF] => "can"
```

Now I have automated this like:

```
stages = ["lidnummer","aardf","prest","dt_prest","aantal","bedrag","verstrekker","foutcode"]
values = ["it","can","be","anything",0,5.3,nil,88] 
stages.each do |c|
  eval "#{c.upcase} = #{stages.index(c)}"
end
p values[AARDF] => "can"
```

But I suppose there is a better Ruby-way to do this, and perhaps without the eval, are there suggestions?

Comment: Magic numbers are `Symbol`s in ruby, so try to do that with them.

Comment: edited the values array to make it more clear what i needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, i learned a lot of this.
Michael was the nearest with his answer but not right (the values array can contain anything, normally it is not the order of the element).
I managed to combine the different techniques here presented and came up with the following.

```
stages = ["lidnummer","aardf","prest","dt_prest","aantal","bedrag","verstrekker","foutcode"]
values = ["it","can","be","anything",0,5.3,nil,88]
stages.each_with_index{|c,i|Object::const_set(c.upcase, i)}
p values[AARDF] => "it"
p values[BEDRAG] => 5.3
```

If i use a Hash it is more error sensitive and i would end using

```
p values[hash["AARDF"]]
```

which is not as smooth

Comment: Please don't add an answer, unless it's the selected solution to the question you originally posted. Instead, modify your original question and append your information above. That makes it easy for someone searching to find your solution, rather than force them to search the entire set.

Comment: Well, Michael was the only one who came near and i edited his answer to solve a bug but even after the correction i think my solution is shorter.., so forgive me to accept my own answer as the best solution unless someone comes up with something even simpler or shorter.

Answer (score 2):

This the easiest I can think of if you insist on doing it the way you described and not using hashes:

```
stages.zip(values) { |stage, value| Object.const_set(stage.upcase, value) }
values[BEDRAG] #=> 5
```

Personally I'd just build a hash, but you know your requirements better than I do:

```
Hash[stages.map(&:upcase).zip(values)]
#=> {"LIDNUMMER"=>0, "AARDF"=>1, "PREST"=>2, "DT_PREST"=>3, "AANTAL"=>4, "BEDRAG"=>5, "VERSTREKKER"=>6, "FOUTCODE"=>7}
```

Comment: @michael what `values[BEDRAG]` mean to you .. i can always access `BEDRAG` directly.

Comment: @SandipRansing He can `const_set` the value to something else, I just wanted to show OP a more idiomatic way to do what he wanted, which is what he asked for.

Comment: @MichaelKohl ah..okk.. Is there any special diff in using `Hash[something]` and `inject({})`

Comment: @SandipRansing They are completely different things. `Hash[]` takes an array of two element arrays and turns it into a hash, whereas `inject` is what's commonly know as a fold in programming: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function) Of course you can use inject for building a hash, but if you already have 2 arrays `zip` + `Hash[]` is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a `Hash` and `Symbol`s.

```
stages = {:aardf => "aardf", :prest => "prest", ...}
stages[:aardf]
```

For legacy, use

```
AARDF = :aardf
```

and

```
stages[AARDF]
```

will still work.

Comment: i allready use hashes for other cases like this<br>
stages = {:aardf => "aardf", :prest => "prest"}<br>
p stages[:aardf]<br>
But sometimes an array is better..In this case i need to be sure no elements are added and that the elements always have the same order

Comment: Tass, i edited my question to better explain what i need, you'll see that a hash here doesn't work as smooth

stages = {:aardf => 1, :prest => 2} 

values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

p values[stages[:aardf]]

Comment: Then use ruby 1.9 and `Hash`, the elements are ordered there.

Answer (score 1):

other way you may get interested -

```
stages = ["lidnummer","aardf","prest","dt_prest","aantal","bedrag","verstrekker","foutcode"]
    values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

stages = stages.zip(values).inject({}) {|h, (k,v)| h[k.upcase]=v;h}
=> {"LIDNUMMER"=>0, "FOUTCODE"=>7, "BEDRAG"=>5, "VERSTREKKER"=>6, "AANTAL"=>4, "PREST"=>2, "AARDF"=>1, "DT_PREST"=>3}


p stages['AARDF'] #=> 1
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not enough, actually there are two arrays, one with the fieldnames and one with the values, i'll edit my question to show this better

Comment: Simpler: `Hash[stages.map(&:upcase).zip(values)]` for the updated question or `Hash[stages.map(&:upcase).zip(stages)]` for the original question.